# Parsing a complex JSON object with Python: search a specific key/value pair

Tags: python, json

**General question**: how can I search a specific `key:value` pair in a JSON using Python?

**Details for the specific case**: I'm reading ~ 45'000 JSON objects, each one of them look [like this one](http://opac.sbn.it/opacmobilegw/search.json?any=Per%20la%20inaugurazione%20dell%27Asilo%20infantile%20Strozzi%20nei%20locali%20della%20caserma%20Filippini%20gi%C3%A0%20convento%20della%20Vittoria%20/%20parole%20di%20mons.%20Carlo%20Savoia&type=0&start=0&rows=3).
As you can see, inside every JSON there are several dictionaries that have the same keys (but different values): `"facetName`, `"facetLabel"`, `"facetValues"`.
I'm interested in the dictionary that starts with `"facetName": "soggettof"`, that goes like:

```
{
  "facetName": "soggettof",
  "facetLabel": "Soggetto",
  "facetValues": [
    [
      "chiesa - storia - documenti",
      "chiesa - storia - documenti",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "espiazione - mare mediterraneo <bacino> - antichita - congressi - munster - 1999",
      "espiazione - mare mediterraneo <bacino> - antichita - congressi - munster - 1999",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "lega rossa combattenti - storia",
      "lega rossa combattenti - storia",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "pavia - storia ecclesiastica - origini-sec. 12.",
      "pavia - storia ecclesiastica - origini-sec. 12.",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "pavia <diocesi> - storia - origini-sec. 12.",
      "pavia <diocesi> - storia - origini-sec. 12.",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "persia - sviluppo economico - 1850-1900 - fonti diplomatiche inglesi",
      "persia - sviluppo economico - 1850-1900 - fonti diplomatiche inglesi",
      "1"
    ]
```

Please note, that not all the JSON objects have that.

How can I grab the values of the `facetValues` list, but only in the dictionary that I'm interested in?

Comment: check if the key exists first, if it does then use it

Comment: Can someone tell me why the question has been downvoted?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hi, thanks. Maybe my question is not clear enough (I'll edit it): the keys "facetName", "facetLabel", "facetValues" are always present, multiple times in the same object, but their values change. I'm interested in the single dictionary that has exactly "facetName": "soggettof",
  "facetLabel": "Soggetto",
  "facetValues": [...]. Hope this clears a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found your question a little confusing, partially because the data shown in it was *not* really the JSON-object you needed to extract the information from—but instead was just an example of a sub-JSON-object you wanted to extract it from. Fortunately you had a [link](http://opac.sbn.it/opacmobilegw/search.json?any=Per%20la%20inaugurazione%20dell%27Asilo%20infantile%20Strozzi%20nei%20locali%20della%20caserma%20Filippini%20gi%C3%A0%20convento%20della%20Vittoria%20/%20parole%20di%20mons.%20Carlo%20Savoia&type=0&start=0&rows=3) to the outermost container JSON-object (even though the data in corresponding sub-JSON-object in it was different). Here's the data from that link:

```
json_obj = {"numFound":1,"start":0,"rows":3,"briefRecords":[{"progressivoId":0,"codiceIdentificativo":"IT\\ICCU\\LO1\\0120590","autorePrincipale":"Savoia, Carlo","titolo":"Per la inaugurazione dell'Asilo infantile Strozzi nei locali della caserma Filippini già convento della Vittoria / parole di mons. Carlo Savoia","pubblicazione":"Mantova : Tip. Eredi Segna, 1870","livello":"Monografia","tipo":"Testo a stampa","numeri":[],"note":[],"nomi":[],"luogoNormalizzato":[],"localizzazioni":[],"citazioni":[]}],"facetRecords":[{"facetName":"level","facetLabel":"Livello bibliografico","facetValues":[["Monografia","m","1"]]},{"facetName":"tiporec","facetLabel":"Tipo di documento","facetValues":[["Testo a stampa","a","1"]]},{"facetName":"nomef","facetLabel":"Autore","facetValues":[["savoia, carlo","savoia, carlo","1"]]},{"facetName":"soggettof","facetLabel":"Soggetto","facetValues":[["mantova - asili infantili","mantova - asili infantili","1"]]},{"facetName":"luogof","facetLabel":"Luogo di pubblicazione","facetValues":[["mantova","mantova","1"]]},{"facetName":"lingua","facetLabel":"Lingua","facetValues":[["italiano","ita","1"]]},{"facetName":"paese","facetLabel":"Paese","facetValues":[["italia","it","1"]]}]}
```

It's important to have this outermost container because it is through it you will have to drill-down to the portion you want. Once you have the actual data It's often helpful to reformat it to make its structure clear. You can do this by hand, or have the computer do it via a `print(json.dumps(json_obj, indent=2))`, although the results from that can sometimes have a little too much white space in them (which can be counterproductive).

That being the case here, below is the more succinct version I came up doing it manually that still let's me see the overall layout of the data:

```
json_obj = {"numFound" : 1,
             "start" : 0,
             "rows" : 3,
             "briefRecords" : [
                {"progressivoId" : 0,
                 "codiceIdentificativo" : "IT\\ICCU\\LO1\\0120590",
                 "autorePrincipale" : "Savoia, Carlo",
                 "titolo" : "Per la inaugurazione dell'Asilo infantile Strozzi nei locali della caserma Filippini già convento della Vittoria / parole di mons. Carlo Savoia",
                 "pubblicazione" : "Mantova : Tip. Eredi Segna, 1870",
                 "livello" : "Monografia",
                 "tipo" : "Testo a stampa",
                 "numeri" : [],
                 "note" : [],
                 "nomi" : [],
                 "luogoNormalizzato" : [],
                 "localizzazioni" : [],
                 "citazioni" : []
                }
             ],
             "facetRecords" : [
                {"facetName" : "level" ,
                 "facetLabel" : "Livello bibliografico" ,
                 "facetValues" : [["Monografia" , "m" , "1"]]},
                {"facetName" : "tiporec" ,
                 "facetLabel" : "Tipo di documento" ,
                 "facetValues" : [["Testo a stampa" , "a" , "1"]]},
                {"facetName" : "nomef" ,
                 "facetLabel" : "Autore" ,
                 "facetValues" : [["savoia, carlo" , "savoia, carlo" , "1"]]},
                {"facetName" : "soggettof" ,
                 "facetLabel" : "Soggetto" ,
                 "facetValues" : [["mantova - asili infantili" , "mantova - asili infantili" , "1"]]},
                {"facetName" : "luogof" ,
                 "facetLabel" : "Luogo di pubblicazione" ,
                 "facetValues" : [["mantova" , "mantova" , "1"]]},
                {"facetName" : "lingua" ,
                 "facetLabel" : "Lingua" ,
                 "facetValues" : [["italiano" , "ita" , "1"]]},
                {"facetName" : "paese" ,
                 "facetLabel" : "Paese" ,
                 "facetValues" : [["italia" , "it" , "1"]]}
             ]
            }
```

Once you have something like this, it's usually fairly easy to determine what code is needed. In this case it's:

```
target_facet_name = "soggettof"

for record in json_obj["facetRecords"]:
    if record["facetName"] == target_facet_name:
        for value in record["facetValues"]:
            print(value)
```

Since `facetRecords` is a `list`, a linear search through them as shown is required to find the one(s) wanted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I edited the question, maybe now it's more clear.

Comment: My code assumes `json_obj` is the dictionary you're interested in. Note a key cannot be present in a dictionary more than once.

Comment: Mmm, ok. But then my problem is exactly that I don't understand how to find my dictionary: inside every dictionary, the keys are present once. But there are 6-7 dictionaries everytime, and mine (I noticed it now) is the third every time there are 7 of them.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. Unfortunately, it seems I cannot explain myself :-( Your code works but it gives me *all* the `facetValues` from all the subobjects. I just need the right one (the dictionary which has `soggetof` as value of the key `facetName`). I tried to explain that in the question (without much success, it seems).

Comment: Yes, it did. I actually noticed that probably the right question should have been "How to find a specific key-value pair in JSON with Python?". Do you think I have to ask that specific (yet more general and more useful) question too?

Comment: Just changing the title of your question would probably suffice.

Comment: ok, done. Hope it's more specific and helpful this way. Don't know if you want to change the answer accordingly.